# sql query to get data month wise in single query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to know how can I fetch data from Database, months wise, using a single query as of now I am fetching data inside the loop which ended up in 12 queries which causing the speed issue. Basically, I need this for the chart. What I am doing is getting months in a year and looping all the months. Inside that loop, i am putting the following query

Here is the query which I am using. I am saving the timestamp for the date.

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS sale
    , COUNT(id) as tot 
  FROM tablename 
 WHERE 1 
   AND ud = 451
   AND oreatedTime BETWEEN 1514782800 AND 1517461199 
   AND uaaZc = "0082844000224"`
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT year(FROM_UNIXTIME(oreatedTime)) as yr,MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(oreatedTime)) as mon,SUM(value) AS sale, COUNT(id) as tot 
FROM tablename WHERE 1 AND ud="451" AND 
oreatedTime BETWEEN 1514782800 AND 1517461199 AND uaaZc = "0082844000224"
group by year(FROM_UNIXTIME(oreatedTime)),MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(oreatedTime))
```

Comment: So `oreatedTime BETWEEN 1514782800 AND 1517461199` i have to put the year timestamp right?

Comment: @jayantrawat, you can check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8650d06d7766e38db1d85aac775b0c0

Comment: Do i still need to put this query inside loop?

Comment: @jayantrawat, no you dont

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. This query is making a huge time difference in loading

Comment: Hi, @fahm this query is working fine, but have one issue with it is if data does not exist for the particular month it doesn't fetch that month. E.g I am fetching data from DEC for the last 6 months, and I don't have any data in Sep and Aug month. Then the query doesn't return any value for that particular month.in which data doesn't exist?